# PGFPlots: make bar in barchart share values at the top of bar

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a PGF bar chart:

```tex
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \centering
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar, axis on top,
        bar width=0.4cm,
        ymax=30,
        width=5.8cm,
        ymajorgrids, tick align=inside,
        major grid style={draw=white},
        enlarge y limits={value=.1,upper},
        ymin=0, 
        tickwidth=0pt,
        enlarge x limits=0.23,
        legend style={
            at={(0.5,-0.2)},
            anchor=north,
            legend columns=-1,
            /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}
        },
        yticklabels={,,},
        x tick label style={font=\scriptsize,text width=1.5cm,align=center},
        symbolic x coords={
            Traditional,
            Optimized,
        CBOR encoded},
        xtick=data,
        nodes near coords={
            \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=2]{\pgfplotspointmeta}
        }
        ]
        \addplot [draw=none, fill=yellow!30] coordinates {
            (Traditional, 27.77)
            (Optimized, 26.43)
            (CBOR encoded, 18.51)
        };
        \addplot [draw=none,fill=yellow!50] coordinates {
            (Traditional, 27.77)
            (Optimized, 23.14)
            (CBOR encoded, 13.88)
        };
        \legend{Client, Master}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

That looks like this:

[image: before]

Obviously, the fact that the first two bars overlap does not look well, as they share the same value (27.77)

How can I make them share a single value, like this? (made by editing the PDF)

[image: after]

Note that I don't want to edit the PDF as I want the graph to be compatible among different document formats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding separate nodes, and using `\usetikzlibrary{calc}`:

```tex
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \centering
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar, axis on top,
        bar width=0.4cm,
        ymax=30,
        width=5.8cm,
        ymajorgrids, tick align=inside,
        major grid style={draw=none},
        enlarge y limits={value=.1,upper},
        ymin=0,
        tickwidth=0pt,
        enlarge x limits=0.23,
        legend style={
            at={(0.5,-0.2)},
            anchor=north,
            legend columns=-1,
            /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}
        },
        yticklabels={,,},
        x tick label style={font=\scriptsize,text width=1.5cm,align=center},
        symbolic x coords={
            Traditional,
            Optimized,
        CBOR encoded},
        xtick=data,
        % nodes near coords={
        %     \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=2]{\pgfplotspointmeta}
        % }
        ]
        \addplot [draw=none, fill=yellow!30] coordinates {
            (Traditional, 27.77)
            (Optimized, 26.43)
            (CBOR encoded, 18.51)
        };
        \addplot [draw=none,fill=yellow!50] coordinates {
            (Traditional, 27.77)
            (Optimized, 23.14)
            (CBOR encoded, 13.88)
        };
        \node[above] at ($(axis cs:Traditional,27.77)+(0,0)$) {27.77};
        \node[above] at ($(axis cs:Optimized,26.43)+(-17,0)$) {26.43};
        \node[above] at ($(axis cs:Optimized,23.14)+(17,0)$) {23.14};
        \node[above] at ($(axis cs:CBOR encoded,18.51)+(-17,0)$) {18.51};
        \node[above] at ($(axis cs:CBOR encoded,13.88)+(17,0)$) {13.88};
        \legend{Client, Master}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```